# How to delete a folder (if it is empty) from Inno Setup code?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I always install a program (`B` = `{app}`) inside of the `C:\A` (`C:\A\B`). I need to know how to use the `DelTree` function to delete `B` folder and `A` folder (the `A` folder only if is empty).

This is my code to delete B folder:

```pascal
DelTree(ExpandConstant('{app}'), True, True, True);
```

---

I need this to rollback an installation of prerequisities, when the installation fails or is cancelled. So I cannot use `UninstallDelete` or `InstallDelete` sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`RemoveDir`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_removedir) and ignore errors.

> Deletes an existing empty directory. The return value is True if a new directory was successfully deleted, or False if an error occurred.

Use [`ExtractFileDir`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extractfiledir) to resolve a path to the parent folder of the `{app}`.

```pascal
RemoveDir(ExtractFileDir(ExpandConstant('{app}')));
```